# Select all <h2> that follow a <p> tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select all headings (in my example `<h2>`) that follow the `<p>` tag?

For example, is it possible for me to select the second and third h2, so that I can put some padding-top?

```
<main>
  <h2>Sub heading 1</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
  <p>More body text</p>
  <h2>Sub heading 2</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
  <h2>Sub heading 3</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
</main>
```

Or to turn it around, select the `<p>` tag that comes before a `<h2>`? To put some padding-bottom?

Thank you

Comment: remember to mark your accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just turns it yellow but you can style it however you want.

```css
p + h2 { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sub heading 1</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
  <p>More body text</p>
  <h2>Sub heading 2</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the CSS Sibling selectors:

The **adjacent sibling combinator** (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it *immediately* follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent `element`.

```
p + h2
```

---

The **general sibling combinator** (~) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it follows the first element (*though not necessarily immediately*), and both are children of the same parent `element`.

```
p ~ h2
```

> UPDATE: I just re-read your question. Currently there is no way to get at a previous sibling or a parent through CSS selectors. But I have hear rumor that those are coming.

Comment: ".. a previous sibling or a parent through CSS selectors.... rumor that those are coming". According to the latest W3C draft, and for many years of drafts previously, through Selectors, yes, through CSS implementations of Selectors, no. Conforming CSS implementations are explicitly barred from supporting this. Of course, browsers may choose to be non-conforming, but this is quite unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're trying to select the second and third h2 use the general sibling (or adjacent) selector followed by `nth-of-type`:

```css
p ~ h2:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-of-type(-n+3) {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>Sub heading 1</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
  <p>More body text</p>
  <h2>Sub heading 2</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
  <h2>Sub heading 3</h2>
  <p>Body text</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. It selects the next element that comes after h2 and if its an element p its going to add some padding-top to it.

```
h2 + p {
  padding-top: 5px
}
```